# Golang fileserver setting content-type differently on linux and macos

Tags: go, webserver, mime-types, fileserver

I am using the `http.FileServer` in my web service, and when I try serving a javascript file from it, I will get a content-type header of `text/javascript; charset=utf-8` on Linux (debian 11), but `application/javascript` on MacOS 13.

Go version is `1.19.1` on linux, and `1.19.3` on MacOS. On both machines I set `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8` in the environment the web service runs in.

Interestingly, when serving other text files, e.g. a HTML file, I will get `text/html; charset=utf-8` on **both** MacOS and Linux.

What is the reason for this? It makes my unit tests fail on MacOS, and I would prefer to test for the full content-type including character set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.FileServer` uses the filename's extension to determine the `Content-Type` if it's not set.  That in turn [calls](https://go.dev/src/net/http/fs.go#L235) `mime.TypeByExtension()`.

The documentation for [`mime.TypeByExtension()`](https://pkg.go.dev/mime#TypeByExtension) says that the mapping is augmented by the system's MIME.info database.  Those are likely different between Linux and MacOS.

@Andrei Vasilev notes that you can override the default mime types with [`AddExtensionType()`](https://pkg.go.dev/mime#AddExtensionType).

Alternatively, you could update the appropriate local `mime.types` file to make them return the same type.  On my MacOS 12.6.1 with go1.19.1 darwin/arm64, I have apache installed and the return value of:

```golang
mime.TypeByExtension(".js")
```

is from `/etc/apache2/mime.types`.

Comment: The [mime](https://pkg.go.dev/mime) package provides [AddExtensionType()](https://pkg.go.dev/mime#AddExtensionType) function to set type. So all you have to do is set the right type, see [example](https://go.dev/play/p/8h5lLZoj5gy).
"application/javascript" [has been rendered obsolete](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/javascript), so setting "text/javascript" would be not a bad idea.

Comment: Great point!  Edited my answer to reflect your suggestion.